# Custom taxonomy name not being translated in post manager page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, translation

I'm having problems trying to display the proper translation for my taxonomy name, specifically in the post manager page. Where it should show the taxonomy's name translated to Spanish, it displays the default one in plain English.

To illustrate my problem, here's an [example](http://postimg.org/image/ptl0to5mv/).

The same things happens with the `popular_items` element, but the rest seems to be working fine, even when the taxonomy name is displayed in the menu.

And here's my code, so you can take a look to how it's been done:

```
function create_entry_level_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Levels', 'dpelt' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'popular_items'         => __( 'Popular Levels' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Levels', 'dpelt' ),
        'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Level:', 'dpelt' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Level', 'dpelt' ),
        'new_item_name'         => __( 'New Level Name', 'dpelt' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No levels found.' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Levels', 'dpelt' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy('entry_level', array('post'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'entry_level' ),
        )
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out. Sometimes writing it down gives you a clearer perspective about your own problem.

I didn't know this before, but `_x()` provides context, and I was providing a context that does not exist. So I just eliminated the whole context thing from the equation by switching the `_x()`s for regular `__()`s and the whole problem was solved :) And well, I forgot to add the text-domain string for `popular_items` and `not_found`, so that part was easy :P

Hope this can also help someone else out there ;)